# Symfony2 Routing - one slug two different routes and Doctrine entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two different Doctrine entities in my Symfony2 application, both entities have slug value, based on which I would like to have routing to be done. I use Annotations. Sample urls as follows:

- http://example.com/city_name_slug
- http://example.com/item_name_slug

As you can see both URLs have a single slug, these slugs never overlap, based on the slug provided I would like to call an action in my Controller.

I can differentiate these 2 URLS if I prepend them with a routing prefix or id, but I don't want to do that; I'd like to keep only single slug.

I could have this done in a single action inside controller, where I would first manually detect match against one entity, and if it's not there match it agains other entity. What I am wondering if there is a better way, like having different routing parameters (I tried with @ParamConverter and no luck).

This is code I have right now, which never gets to the second action(), the first action is always being triggered.

**First action:**

```
* @Route("/{_locale}/{deal}/{city_slug}/{page}", defaults={"page"=1}, requirements={
 *    "_locale": "en|tm",
 *    "page": "\d+",
 *    "deal": "value1|value2"
 * }, name="deal_cities")
 *
 */
public function cityAction($page, $city_slug, $deal=null){
  ...
}
```

**Second action inside same Controller:**

```
* @Route("/{_locale}/{deal}/{item_slug}/{page}", defaults={"page"=1}, requirements={
     *    "_locale": "en|tm",
     *    "page": "\d+",
     *    "deal": "value1|value2"
     * }, name="deal_items")
     *
     */
    public function itemAction($page, $item_slug, $deal=null){
      ...
    }
```

**I also tried with ParamConverter but no luck getting to the second action:**

```
   ...
  * @ParamConverter("city", options={"mapping": {"city_slug": "slug"}})
     *
     */
    public function cityAction($page, City $city, $deal=null){
     ....
    }
```

Advice appreciated.

Comment: All Symfony get via request only a string `/path/slug`. How do you expect it to understand is it city or other without checking for db or other data storage?

Comment: I understand that, that's why was wondering if there is a way, maybe with proper ParamConverter usage or something else, in case I misunderstood something.

Comment: You can add additional db table with slug, entity type, entity id, and make front controller to redirect to another with entity id parameter.

Comment: I have a working solution that suits me, where I catch slug, and interpret it inside a single action(). I was wondering if in Symfony there existed a way of doing it as is described in the question.

Comment: Have you tried to make it with yml?